# Update values in a table based on specific values

Tags: excel, vba, loops, match, paste

I'm trying to copy and paste, using a loop, match and offset.

In the Update sheet I have a table where a user will update values

```
    A           B       C              D              E
1   PrimaryKey  Line    New Value 1    New Value 2    UpdateValue
2   XY.1        1       ABCD           1234           1
3   XY.2        2       ZXCV           9876           1
4
```

I need to do the following.

1. Search Sheet2 (Table1[PrimaryKey]) and match based on cell A2 value
2. Copy value in C2 in Sheet 1 (e.g. ABCD)
3. Paste.Values in Lx (where x =row id found in step 1)
4. Copy value in CD in Sheet 1 (e.g. 1234)
5. Paste.Values in Ox (where x =row id found in step 1)
6. Paste today() in Wx
7. Loop for all cells where Column E = 1

This is the code I found. I could not figure out the loop, and the match components.

```vb
'Set sheets   
Set sh1 = Sheets("Data Capture")   
Set sh2 = Sheets("DataTable")      

'Find string in column A of Sheet2   
Set foundCell = sh2.Range("Table5[PrimaryKey]").Find(sh1.Range("Z2").Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)   
If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then 'If match cell is found     
    sh1.Range("B2").Copy     
    foundCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues     
    foundCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats     
    Application.CutCopyMode = False   
Else   

End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: Which specific part of this is giving you problems?

Comment: all of it. i found some code, however i couldnt understand it to adapt it to what i needed.

Comment: `'Set sheets
  Set sh1 = Sheets("Data Capture")
  Set sh2 = Sheets("DataTable")
  
  'Find string in column A of Sheet2
  Set foundCell = sh2.Range("Table5[PrimaryKey]").Find(sh1.Range("Z2").Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
  If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then 'If match cell is found
    sh1.Range("B2").Copy
    foundCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    foundCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Else
  End If
End Sub`

Comment: this is the code i found, however i could figure out the loop, and the match components.

Comment: As you figured out the loop and match components all you do is edit to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood your problem but I tried to rebuild your table. So I named the first sheet "Sheet1", copied your table from your question in A1-E3, named a second sheet "Sheet2" and wrote "XY.1" and "XY.2" in A1-A2.

Maybe the following macro will help you. It takes the values writen in your table (on "Sheet1"), goes to "Sheet2", searches in the first column for a value and writes the other things to Columns L, O and W. But I did not understand what to do with the values in column B of your table!?

```
Sub NameYourMacro()

Dim i As Integer
Dim strTheRow As String
Dim strNewValue1 As String
Dim strNewValue2 As String
Dim rngFoundCell As Range

i = 2 'First row on Sheet1 with values is row 2
While Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" 'while there is a value in column A
    
    If Cells(i, 5).Value = 1 Then 'if value in column E is 1 then to things
    
        'Read Values:
        strTheRow = Cells(i, 1).Value
        strNewValue1 = Cells(i, 3).Value
        strNewValue2 = Cells(i, 4).Value
    
        'go to Sheet2 and search in the first column
        Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
        Set rngFoundCell = Columns(1).Find(strTheRow, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rngFoundCell Is Nothing Then 'if vba found the value in column 1
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("L" & rngFoundCell.Row).Value = strNewValue1
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("O" & rngFoundCell.Row).Value = strNewValue2
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("W" & rngFoundCell.Row).Value = Date
        Else
            'if rngFoundCell is nothing (value not found) do nothing
        End If
    Else
        'if value in column E is not 1 do nothing
    End If

    'go back to Sheet1 and next row...
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub
```